# draw on canvas without removing the background image on erase function

Tags: android, canvas, android-canvas

I am trying to draw and erase on image and then save it to sd card. I got success in drawing and saving it to sd card, but when i checked the save image in sd card I got a black background image not the image at i draw.

Please suggest me how to apply image as a canvas background and erase draw text without losing the background image. I have seen various example on stack overflow but my bad no one is working for me, pls help.

What I need :

[image]

What I am getting from sd card :

[image]

Here is my effort :

```
public class HomeActivity extends Activity {
private Bitmap DrawBitmap;
private Canvas mCanvas;
private Path mPath;
private Paint DrawBitmapPaint;
RelativeLayout Rl;
CustomView View;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.home);

    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

    this.loadActivity();
}

private Paint mPaint;

public class CustomView extends View {

    public CustomView(Context c) {

        super(c);

        create_image();

        setLayerType(android.view.View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, mPaint);

    }

    @Override
    protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
        // mCanvas.drawColor(Color.BLUE);

        super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
        canvas.drawBitmap(DrawBitmap, 0, 0, DrawBitmapPaint);
        canvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);

        canvas.drawRect(mY, 0, mY, 0, DrawBitmapPaint);
    }

    private float mX, mY;
    private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 4;

    private void touch_start(float x, float y) {
        mPath.reset();
        mPath.moveTo(x, y);
        mX = x;
        mY = y;
    }

    private void touch_move(float x, float y) {
        float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
        float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
        if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
            mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX) / 2, (y + mY) / 2);
            mX = x;
            mY = y;
        }
    }

    private void touch_up() {
        mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);

        mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);

        mPath.reset();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX();
        float y = event.getY();

        switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            touch_start(x, y);
            invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            touch_move(x, y);
            invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            touch_up();
            performClick();
            invalidate();
            break;
        }
        return true;
    }

    public void clear() {
        create_image();

        // Added later..
        mPaint = new Paint();
        mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
        mPaint.setDither(true);
        mPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        // mCanvas.drawColor(Color.BLUE);
        mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(12);
        this.invalidate();
    }

}

public void loadActivity() {

    View = new CustomView(this);
    Rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.Rel);
    Rl.addView(View);
    mPaint = new Paint();
    mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    mPaint.setDither(true);
    // mCanvas.drawColor(Color.BLUE);
    mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    mPaint.setStrokeWidth(10);

}

public void create_image() {

    DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
    int screenWidth = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
    int screenHeight = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
    DrawBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(screenWidth, screenHeight,
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444);

    mCanvas = new Canvas(DrawBitmap);
    mCanvas.drawColor(R.drawable.myBackgroundImage);

    mPath = new Path();
    DrawBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.action_menu, menu);

    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    mPaint.setXfermode(null);
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.erase:
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(40);

        mPaint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(10);

        break;
    case R.id.DELETE:

        View.clear();
        mCanvas.drawColor(Color.BLUE);
        break;
    case R.id.color_Red:
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(8);
        mPaint.setColor(Color.RED);

        break;
    case R.id.color_Green:
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(8);
        mPaint.setColor(Color.GREEN);

        break;
    case R.id.color_Yello:
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(8);
        mPaint.setColor(Color.YELLOW);

        break;

    case R.id.color_Black:
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(8);
        mPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);

        break;

    case R.id.draw:
        mPaint.setStrokeWidth(8);
        mPaint.setXfermode(null);

        break;

    case R.id.Save:
        String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
        File myDir = new File(root + "/saved_images");
        myDir.mkdirs();
        Random generator = new Random();
        int n = 10000;
        n = generator.nextInt(n);
        String fname = "Image-" + n + ".jpg";
        File file = new File(myDir, fname);
        if (file.exists())
            file.delete();

        try {
            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            DrawBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
            out.flush();
            out.close();
            Toast.makeText(this, "File Saved ::" + fname,
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_MOUNTED,
                    Uri.parse("file://"
                            + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "ERROR" + e.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                    .show();
        }
    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem by using this code.
When u save this just draw bitmap on canvas with your desire background.

```
public class DrawingView extends View {


public Paint mPaint;
public int width;
public int height;
private Bitmap mBitmap;
private Canvas mCanvas;
private Path mPath;
private Paint mBitmapPaint;
static Context context;
private Paint circlePaint;
public boolean eraseMode = false;
private Path circlePath;

public DrawingView(Context c) {
    super(c);
    context = c;
    initialize();
}

public void initialize(){
    mPath = new Path();
    mBitmapPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
    circlePaint = new Paint();
    circlePath = new Path();
    circlePaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    circlePaint.setColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
    circlePaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    circlePaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.MITER);
    circlePaint.setStrokeWidth(4f);
    mPaint = new Paint();
    mPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    mPaint.setDither(true);
    mPaint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    mPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    mPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    mPaint.setStrokeWidth(6);
}

@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);

    mBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    mCanvas = new Canvas(mBitmap);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawBitmap(mBitmap, 0, 0, mBitmapPaint);
    canvas.drawPath(circlePath, circlePaint);
    super.onDraw(canvas);
}

private float mX, mY;
private static final float TOUCH_TOLERANCE = 4;

private void touch_start(float x, float y) {
    mPath.reset();
    mPath.moveTo(x, y);
    mX = x;
    mY = y;
}

private void touch_move(float x, float y) {
    float dx = Math.abs(x - mX);
    float dy = Math.abs(y - mY);
    if (dx >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE || dy >= TOUCH_TOLERANCE) {
        mPath.quadTo(mX, mY, (x + mX) / 2, (y + mY) / 2);
        mX = x;
        mY = y;

        circlePath.reset();
        circlePath.addCircle(mX, mY, 30, Path.Direction.CW);
        mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
    }
}

private void touch_up() {
    mPath.lineTo(mX, mY);
    circlePath.reset();
    mCanvas.drawPath(mPath, mPaint);
    mPath.reset();
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    float x = event.getX();
    float y = event.getY();

    switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        touch_start(x, y);
        invalidate();
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        touch_move(x, y);
        invalidate();
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        touch_up();
        invalidate();
        break;
    }
    return true;
}

public void setErase() {
    mPaint.setXfermode(null);
    mPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
    eraseMode = true;
}

public void removeErase() {
    mPaint.setXfermode(null);
     eraseMode = false;
}

public void SaveImage() {
    Bitmap image1 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(mBitmap, 1080, 780, true);

    File filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File file = new File(filepath.getAbsolutePath() + "/NumberAndAlphabet");
    if (!file.exists()) {
        file.mkdir();
    }
    Date date = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis());
    SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddHHmmss",
            Locale.getDefault());
    String time = formatter.format(date);
    File dir = new File(file, "Image" + time + ".PNG");
    OutputStream output = null;
    try {
        output = new FileOutputStream(dir);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Bitmap newbitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(image1.getWidth(), image1.getHeight(), image1.getConfig());
    Canvas can = new Canvas(newbitmap);
    can.drawColor(Color.WHITE);
    can.drawBitmap(image1, 0, 0, null);
    newbitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, output);
    Toast.makeText(context, "Image Saved...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
```

}

Comment: on touch app crashes each time.

Comment: can you post your logcat?

Comment: logcat showing problem with  circlePath.reset(); inside touch_up()

Comment: can you post fully logcat because without seeing logcat i m not able to tell solution

Comment: have you create the object of Paint method mPaint in your activity?

Comment: ok i m adding full code in answer and then add this view in your layout and let me know this will help u or not?

Comment: add this to ur layout dynamically or in Xml file

Comment: Hey sagar, i thing here is a communication gap b/w u and me....I need a image at the background of canvas......not the color. Thats my problem.

Comment: there is function in code name saveImage.In this function you have to get the DrawingCache of your main view and create bitmap and save it and remove the last line of function which is related to canvas and u will get desire result